Python - Subtract Date by First Entry?
I'm using polars library in python to manipulate some dataframe.
I'm trying to do the following:
:
For some dataframe:



Person..
Fight with
On




A
B
3 Jan


A
C
4 Jan


A
D
5 Jan


A
E
5 Jan


A
B
10 Jan


A
B
20 Jan


A
C
20 Jan



I want to return the "distance" between the current fighter-pair and the first fight they had, such that:
:



Person..
Fight with
On
Distance




A
B
3 Jan
0 Days


A
C
4 Jan
0 Days


A
D
5 Jan
0 Days


A
E
5 Jan
0 Days


A
B
10 Jan
7 Days   (i.e. 10 Jan - 3 Jan); (CurrentDate - ABFirstFight)


A
B
20 Jan
17 Days  (i.e. 20 Jan - 3 Jan); (CurrentDate - ABFirstFight)


A
C
20 Jan
16 Days  (i.e. 20 Jan - 4 Jan); (CurrentDate - ACFirstFight)



<What I've Tried>:

polars "first" function: Only returned the head of the dataframe
polars "first" function with some combinations of "over"/"group_by"/"rolling" functions: Returned some numbers, but I can't make sense of why the output was that way

Does anyone have any advice on how to attempt this?
I think I might need to use some combination of "group_by" or "over", "first", and perhaps "sub" (to subtract two dates?), but I'm not sure how to proceed.
The hardest part for me is  to try to extract the first entry of a given group (e.g. first date entry of the A-B pair, or the A-C pair, etc.)

Here's one way to do this:
Group the dataframe by [person, fight_with], select the min on, and then join it with the original dataframe.
Here's some code:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "person": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "fight_with": ["B", "C", "D", "E", "B", "B", "C"],
        "on": [3, 4, 5, 5, 10, 20, 20],
    }
)

first_fight = df.group_by("person", "fight_with").agg(pl.min("on").alias("min_on"))

df = df.join(first_fight, on=["person", "fight_with"]).with_columns(
    distance=pl.col("on") - pl.col("min_on")
)

print(df)

Output:
shape: (7, 5)
┌────────┬────────────┬─────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ person ┆ fight_with ┆ on  ┆ min_on ┆ distance │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64 ┆ i64    ┆ i64      │
╞════════╪════════════╪═════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ A      ┆ B          ┆ 3   ┆ 3      ┆ 0        │
│ A      ┆ C          ┆ 4   ┆ 4      ┆ 0        │
│ A      ┆ D          ┆ 5   ┆ 5      ┆ 0        │
│ A      ┆ E          ┆ 5   ┆ 5      ┆ 0        │
│ A      ┆ B          ┆ 10  ┆ 3      ┆ 7        │
│ A      ┆ B          ┆ 20  ┆ 3      ┆ 17       │
│ A      ┆ C          ┆ 20  ┆ 4      ┆ 16       │
└────────┴────────────┴─────┴────────┴──────────┘


Thanks! As a sidenote, using the following also works:   agg(pl.first("on")

Yes, pl.first("on") would give the same result faster as long as your array is sorted by on.

As you have stated, you can get the first .over() each group.
df.with_columns(
   pl.format("{} - {}", pl.col("On"), pl.col("On").first())
     .over("Person..", "Fight with")
)

shape: (7, 3)
┌──────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ Person.. ┆ Fight with ┆ On             │
│ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str      ┆ str        ┆ str            │
╞══════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ A        ┆ B          ┆ 3 Jan - 3 Jan  │
│ A        ┆ C          ┆ 4 Jan - 4 Jan  │
│ A        ┆ D          ┆ 5 Jan - 5 Jan  │
│ A        ┆ E          ┆ 5 Jan - 5 Jan  │
│ A        ┆ B          ┆ 10 Jan - 3 Jan │
│ A        ┆ B          ┆ 20 Jan - 3 Jan │
│ A        ┆ C          ┆ 20 Jan - 4 Jan │
└──────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘

See Window functions in the user guide:

https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/window/

